# Expanding Tables

Tags: html, css, html-table

Ive got my example pretty close ..but having an issue understanding how to make the  expand to take up the space of 2 ..well im bad at explaining anything let me just post my code and my example and youll see what i mean.

```
    <!Doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="schedule.css">


        <title>My Sample ScheduleR_M</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>R_M Fake Winter Schedule</h1>
        <table>
        <caption>
        Winter
        <br>
        2016
        <br>
        Schedule
        </caption>
            <tr>
                <th>       </th>
                <th>Monday</th>
                <th>Tuesday</th>
                <th>Wednesday</th>
                <th>Thursday</th>
                <th>Friday</th>
            </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>8:30</td>
            <td>IS 210</td>
            <td>IS 210</td>
            <td>IS 210</td>
            <td>IS 210</td>
            <td>IS 210</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>9:30</td>
            <td>Office Hours</td>
            <td>IS 107</td>
            <td>IS 107</td>
            <td>IS 107</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>10:30</td>
            <td>IS 105</td>
            <td>IS 105</td>
            <td>IS 105</td>
            <td rowspan="2" class="space">     </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>11:30</td>
            <td>IS 120</td>
            <td>IS 120</td>
            <td>IS 120</td>
            <td>      </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>12:30</td>
            <td>Lunch</td>
        </tr>

    </table>
    </body>
    </html>


    table {
        margin-left: 20px;
        margin-right: 20px;
        border: thick solid green;
        caption-side: right;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }

    h1  {
        color: red;
        border-bottom: thin dotted red;
    }

    td, th {
        border: thin dotted gray;
        padding: 5px;

    }

    th   {
        color: orange;
        background-color: purple;

    }
  td:first-child {
        color: orange;
        background-color: purple;
    }


    caption {
        font-style: italic;

    }
```

[THIS IS ThE Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C09sn.jpg)  
i get it in .pdf format i cannot inspect and simply look just to get that out the way, if someone can explain what im doing wrong..like i said i feel close...thanks guys hope i supplied enough information

---

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="schedule.css">


    <title>My Sample ScheduleR_M</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>R_M Fake Winter Schedule</h1>
    <table>
    <caption>
    Winter
    <br>
    2016
    <br>
    Schedule
    </caption>
        <tr>
            <th>       </th>
            <th>Monday</th>
            <th>Tuesday</th>
            <th>Wednesday</th>
            <th>Thursday</th>
            <th>Friday</th>
        </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>8:30</td>
        <td>IS 210</td>
        <td>IS 210</td>
        <td>IS 210</td>
        <td>IS 210</td>
        <td>IS 210</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>9:30</td>
        <td colspan="2" style="background-color: #D3D3D3; text-align: center;">Break time</td>
        <td>IS 107</td>
        <td>IS 107</td>
        <td>IS 107</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>10:30</td>
        <td>IS 105</td>
        <td>IS 105</td>
        <td>IS 105</td>
        <td rowspan="2" colspan="2" style="background-color: #D3D3D3; text-align: center;">break time</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>11:30</td>
        <td>IS 120</td>
        <td>IS 120</td>
        <td>IS 120</td>
        <td>      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>12:30</td>
        <td colspan="5" style="background-color: gray; text-align: center;">Lunch</td>
    </tr>

</table>
</body>
</html>


table {
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    border: thick solid green;
    caption-side: right;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

h1  {
    color: red;
    border-bottom: thin dotted red;
}

td, th {
    border: thin dotted gray;
    padding: 5px;

}

th   {
    color: orange;
    background-color: purple;

}
 td:first-child {
    color: orange;
    background-color: purple;
}


caption {
    font-style: italic;

}
```

the above code is causing there to be a empty new tr column what am i doing wrong..?  thanks guys!

Comment: I searched google for "html table merge cells" and found this http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001655.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic principle of rowspans and colspans is: If you use for example a `rowspan:2` in a `td` in the first row, your second row has to have one column less than the first, since that one cell extends down from the top to the second row. The same with colspans.

If you have a colspan = 5 in a row like in your last row, you only need 2 cells/`td`s, since 1 + 5 adds up to the 6 that the other rows have.

I recreated your example with colspans and rowspans below. I also assigned a class called "center" to the `td`s that span several columns to center the text in those larger cells.

```css
table {
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    border: thick solid green;
    caption-side: right;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

h1  {
    color: red;
    border-bottom: thin dotted red;
}

td, th {
    border: thin dotted gray;
    padding: 5px;

}

th   {
    color: orange;
    background-color: purple;

}
 td:first-child {
    color: orange;
    background-color: purple;
}


caption {
    font-style: italic;

}
.center { text-align: center; }
```

```html
<table>
        <caption>
        Winter
        <br>
        2016
        <br>
        Schedule
        </caption>
            <tr>
                <th>       </th>
                <th>Monday</th>
                <th>Tuesday</th>
                <th>Wednesday</th>
                <th>Thursday</th>
                <th>Friday</th>
            </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>8:30</td>
            <td>IS 210</td>
            <td>IS 210</td>
            <td>IS 210</td>
            <td>IS 210</td>
            <td>IS 210</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>9:30</td>
            <td colspan="2" class="center" >Office Hours</td>
            <td>IS 107</td>
            <td>IS 107</td>
            <td>IS 107</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>10:30</td>
            <td>IS 105</td>
            <td>IS 105</td>
            <td>IS 105</td>
            <td rowspan="2" colspan="2" class="center"> Office Hours</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>11:30</td>
            <td>IS 120</td>
            <td>IS 120</td>
            <td>IS 120</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>12:30</td>
            <td colspan="5" class="center">Lunch</td>
        </tr>

    </table>
```

Answer (score 3):

USe `colspan` to merge cells horizontally and `rowspan` to merge cells vertically.

Here is updated snippet, I have removed some extra td.

```css
    table {
        margin-left: 20px;
        margin-right: 20px;
        border: thick solid green;
        caption-side: right;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }

    h1  {
        color: red;
        border-bottom: thin dotted red;
    }

    td, th {
        border: thin dotted gray;
        padding: 5px;

    }

    th   {
        color: orange;
        background-color: purple;

    }
  td:first-child {
        color: orange;
        background-color: purple;
    }


    caption {
        font-style: italic;

    }
```

```html
<!Doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="schedule.css">


        <title>My Sample ScheduleR_M</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>R_M Fake Winter Schedule</h1>
        <table>
        <caption>
        Winter
        <br>
        2016
        <br>
        Schedule
        </caption>
            <tr>
                <th>       </th>
                <th>Monday</th>
                <th>Tuesday</th>
                <th>Wednesday</th>
                <th>Thursday</th>
                <th>Friday</th>
            </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>8:30</td>
            <td>IS 210</td>
            <td>IS 210</td>
            <td>IS 210</td>
            <td>IS 210</td>
            <td>IS 210</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>9:30</td>
            <td colspan="2">Office Hours</td>
            <td>IS 107</td>
            <td>IS 107</td>
            <td>IS 107</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>10:30</td>
            <td>IS 105</td>
            <td>IS 105</td>
            <td>IS 105</td>
            <td rowspan="2" colspan="2" class="space">  Office Space   </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>11:30</td>
            <td>IS 120</td>
            <td>IS 120</td>
            <td>IS 120</td>
           
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>12:30</td>
            <td colspan="5">Lunch</td>
        </tr>

    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```